# Get value from different form using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, pug

I want to get a value (in my case `#{item.description}`) from client to server. Here is my html code in pug template.

```
each item, index in items
  form#myForm.MyForm
    .container
      #allLessons.container
        .lessonsWrap
          h3.lesson #{index+1} . Lesson |
          p#lessonText.lesson(style='margin-left:1%;' type="desc" name='desc') #{item.description}
          a(href=)
            button#butPam.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Begin
          .about
            p(style='margin-left:1%;') Lecturer: #{item.author}
            p(style='margin-left:1%;') Level: #{item.level}
```

And here is ajax script:

```
script.
  $('.MyForm').on('submit', function(event){
    var createVar = $("#lessonText").html();
    var dataToSend = createVar;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/qVal',
      method: 'post',
      data: {'desc':createVar},
      async: true,
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
    event.preventDefault();

  });
```

For example, when I click on submit button in second or third form, I always get value from first form. Probably I need to use $(this) in .MyForm or in data but I don't know how correctly to do that.

Comment: Id suppose to be unique so you can use class instead for `#pamokaText` elements, after change it to class you can then use `(".pamokaText")` but while `#pamokaText` element is not clear in your code I couldn't know the relation between the `form` and `#pamokaText` element .. if it's a form child so you can use `$(this).find(".pamokaText").html()`

Comment: My bad, it should be a #lessonText

Comment: same way.. change to classes `p.lessonText` instead of ids `p#lessonText` and use `$(this).find(".lessonText").html()`

Comment: Thanks Mohamed-Yousef, that helped!